# How to get list of apps installed from external storage using OSGI Bundle?

Tags: android, android-intent, osgi-bundle

Im using OSGI Bundle (that its in my storage) and i want to get list of applications installed in my smartphone. Im using the following method but im always getting a null list, as if my smartphone wasnt have any app. I think it should be because the bundle is in the storage (different of a launcher application).

This code works in a normal application, but when using it in a bundle dont.

My bundle is the folder: 0 -> Android -> Data -> com.myapp -> felix -> availablebundles -> myBundle.jar

Thats the code i use to get the apps installed:

```
private String findTargetAppPackage(Intent intent) {
        PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> availableApps = new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();
        try{
        availableApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("EXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
        }

        try{
        if (availableApps != null) {
          for (ResolveInfo availableApp : availableApps) {
            String packageName = availableApp.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (targetApplications.contains(packageName)) {
              return packageName;
            }
          }
        }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return null;
      }
```

EDIT: Thats what intent receive as category.

```
Intent intentScan = new Intent(BS_PACKAGE + ".SCAN");
intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: What is the content of the `intent` parameter when you call this method?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used OSGI Bundle so I'm afraid I can't help you here.

Comment: Oh..i understand...this is a very closed feature...few people use this. But cost nothing to try. HAHAHA